# Is there any native implementation of circuit breaker pattern in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, akka.net, azure-service-fabric, circuit-breaker

I'd like to wrap the calls to dependencies in a circuit breaker/timeouts/retries in the same way Hystrix or Akka.net do, but because I'm building cloud services and worker roles in azure, I'm wondering if there is an azure implementation that will allow us to do that.

Is there any native azure way to do this? I was looking at service fabric but I'm not sure if it does that, we want to implement our services over azure platform, not over azure infrastructure.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589784.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no circuit breaker library from Microsoft. I have used [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) with great success.

It is really easy to use

```
var policy = Policy
  .Handle<TimeoutException>()
  .CircuitBreaker(2, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

var result = policy.Execute(() => FetchData(p1, p2));
```

Read more about it in my blog post: [Automatic Retry and Circuit Breaker made easy](http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2013/08/07/automatic-retry-and-circuit-breaker-made-easy/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. By the way, the question was more to know if there is something out there targeted to AZure, and the answer was a clear no. I think Akka.net is very complete framework, but Polly seems more lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a long list of cloud design patterns architectures available on msdn for circuit breaker

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589784.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several Hystrix ports for .NET like
https://github.com/Elders/Hystrix.NET
https://github.com/Travix-International/Hystrix.Dotnet

Also some Circuit Breaker samples in Azure documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/circuit-breaker
https://microserviceswithazure.com/Samples/Circuit%20Breaker.html

Also, Steeltoe, which enable using Hystrix & Eureka from .NET
https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/CircuitBreaker